# Derive open-loop frequency response from close-loop characteristic

Tags: operational-amplifier, frequency, ota

How can I derive open-loop frequency response from close-loop characteristic of a real Operational transconductance amplifier?

Comment: Welcome to the EE Stack Exchange. Please attach the equation for the transfer function you are working with. Thanks.

Comment: With a carefully chosen open loop function, and a synthetic (zero noise) closed loop function, it may be possible to recover the former from the latter. With realistic noise errors on the measurement of a closed loop function, recovering an open loop function in the general case is impractical.

Answer (score 1):

The closed-loop gain Acl for an amplifier with negative feeedback is

**Acl=Aol/(1+Hf*Aol)** with Aol=open loop gain and Hf=Feedback function.

Therefore, without knowing the function Hf it is not possible to derive the expression for Aol from the closed-loop function.

Comment: Thanks, Are you know any approach to measure this open loop transfer function from fabricated close looped amplifier? (HF = 1)